# Allow user's pictures to have transparent background

Tags: feature-request

I recently uploaded a picture with a warning sign. That just looks attractive, but I found, the horizontal bar at the top (in the picture below) had white background.

[image]

So, instead, I edited it and made the background transparent, but when I again uploaded, I ended up having a black background on both profile and the bar.

[image]

The photo should be made compatible to transparent background. This will make it more attractive and efficient in case the user wants to add a transparent background.

Comment: This is probably a question for the meta stackexchange but I'd be surprised if it wasn't a duplicate

Comment: Well, I am active only at StackOverflow, so, the thought of putting it here just struck my head. And why do you think it would be a duplicate?

Comment: Error - Given the websites age, I can't imagine you are the first user to want a transparent background

Comment: I may not be the first user wanting transparent background but maybe I am the first user who asked it, everyone else ignored? Who knows? It would be kind of you if you find out any duplicate.

Comment: I found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163831/profile-picture-cannot-have-transparent-background) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210132/new-top-bar-should-render-avatar-with-a-transparent-background) by searching on google for "meta stackoverflow: transparent background" although the latter doesn't have an accepted answer it may appear that the problem is known

Comment: Works with gravatar (note, I've set the div background to red to make it easy to see) http://i.stack.imgur.com/eDETs.png